# Umbraco backend properties seem to overlay when switching tabs

Tags: umbraco

I've got a bit of an issue with Umrbaco at the moment. When ever I log into the back end the properties seem to come from other tabs onto the current page (almost as if they aren't hidden correctly).

[My view from the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcAzI.png)

This is also happening on each page but is spreading macros across different tabs (I can provide screenshots if needed).

Just wondering if anyone else has experienced anything like this before and has a resolution, as my google skills haven't been able to find anything that can help.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your Umbraco version.

Comment: It might be worth looking for an issue on http://issues.umbraco.org, or posting your bug there.

Comment: Hi Harvey, I have posted this issue to the umbraco forum but to no avail.

Comment: This is the umbraco version I am using Umbraco version 7.5.6 assembly: 1.0.6185.24083 @Harvey

Comment: Thanks, and which browser?

Comment: @Harvey This is happening in Chrome